# Is there a size difference between importing a component locally or globally?

Tags: webpack

Using Vue I have two options:

1. I can import a Component directly to my main Vue with for example:

   ```
   Vue.component('modal', require('./components/modal.vue'));
   ```
2. Or I can import it locally inside another Component, let's say:

   ```
   //Inside Component
   import 'modal' from './components/modal'
   export default {
      components: {modal}
   }
   ```

Now if I use the second option over and over again. Will Webpack import this component over and over again? Thus, creating more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, each module would be specified only once per bundle (they might be duplicated if you use dynamic imports, which would end up with multiple chunks, though with webpack 4 it would be optimized automatically).

While you using import statement (`import ... from '...'`) you don't have to worry about it